# How do I detect memory leaks using the tools in CRT in a C++/Java project using JNI?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I've been trying for a few hours now to get it working. So far it does find memory leaks but it finds a ton and I'm not sure if that's realistic. Also I'd like to see the file and line number (I know it's possible but I can't get it to work) so that I can actually solve the memory leaks.

I have added the code to dump memory leaks in a method that is frequently called (about 60 times per second normally), I'm not sure if it's ok or not but since I don't really have a "main" function it's hard to decide where to put the code.

Here is what I have added :

```
// This part is in the includes part of the file
#define _CRTDBG_MAPALLOC
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC_NEW
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

// This part is in the method
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try deleaker or similar debugger - it help to control the memory leaks and user objects...   it will indicate the line that located a bug.

Comment: The thing is my file is a .jar and deleaker will only accept a .exe. Do you know any similar tool that would work with a Java program that calls C++ code through JNI? Thanks.

Comment: Every allocation is a leak when you call _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() all the time.  Consider using DllMain() for a good trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Visual Leak Detector

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9815/Visual-Leak-Detector-Enhanced-Memory-Leak-Detectio

I had very good results with it.

Answer (score 0):

With a crt you have the possibility to compare the memory state before perform an action and after that. In order to achieve this just use the _CrtMemDifference in your unit tests. The concept is to write the unit-tests which will call a different parts of your code and will get the state of the application memory before by using the _CrtMemCheckpoint and after the call. So after that you have to compare two checkpoints with the _CrtMemDifference.